# Create ViewBag properties based on strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

Is there any way to create and use dynamic properties for ViewBag, based on strings?

Something like

```
ViewBag.CreateProperty("MyProperty");
ViewBag.Property("MyProperty") = "Myvalue";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I just found  out that ViewData can be used to create such properties for ViewBag

So to create property CityErrorMessage I have to use

```
ViewData.Add("CityErrorMessage", MyErrorMessage)
```

and then in the view I can use

```
@ViewBag.CityErrorMessage
```

**EDIT:**

I created the ViewBag's properties dynamically, because I received the name of field with validation error in a list

So the code actually is

```
foreach (ValidationError err in ValidationErrors)
{
    ViewData.Add(
        string.format("{0}ErrorMsg", err.PropertyName),
        err.ValidationErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining the relationship between ViewBag and ViewData

Comment: Should be noted that you can use `ViewData["NameHere"]` to dynamically get the value of the items you have stored.

Answer (score -3):

Update: I belatedly realised that this code comes from a Nancy project and Nancy implements it's own ViewBag so this code does not work with .Net MVC3 and does not answer the question. However, it might be argued that the question could be solved by switching to Nancy.

I found ViewBag has an `Add` method so you can do this:

```
foreach(var row in model)
            {
                ViewBag.Add(row.resourceName, row.content);
            }
```

Comment: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Additional information: 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Comment: I will check the project I have with this code working. It seems others are not able to replicate it.

Comment: Having error: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code