# How can I make these if statement better?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am very new to C# and I have a question. I didn't find the right answer on google but how can I simplify or clean up this code.

```
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table1") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table1FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table2") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table2FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table3") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table3FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table4") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table4FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table5") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table5FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table6") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table6FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table7") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table7FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == "Table8") == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Table8FillColor = "#ff1200";
    }
```

Comment: If this works, what is the problem?

Comment: You can optimize execution by using if/else so you don't execute all the ifs unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok, thnx nicomp. And the problem is that I want to have my code so clean as possible @DavidG . I don't want to learn the wrong ways of coding.

Comment: What exactly does "better" mean?

Answer (score 4):

Setting values in ViewData is effectively the same as dynamic properties in ViewBag (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936175/728795)). This allows for a nice solution using arrays:

```
string[] tableNames = new string[]{"Table1", "Table2", ...};
string[] tableColorProperties = new string[]{"Table1FillColor", "Table2FillColor", ...};

for(int i=0; i<tableNames.Length; i++)
{
    if (availableTables.Any(item => item.Name == tableNames[i]) == false)
    {
        ViewData.Add(tableColorProperties[i], "#ff1200");
    }
}
```

This can be improved further based on personal taste: use dictionary instead of two arrays, LINQ, so on.

I have to say though that you should probably consider refactoring your controller-view data passing to use strongly typed models.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have anything where there can be an arbitrary number of tables, you could match with `Regex` and add them accordingly:

```
var names = new List<string>
{
    "Table1", "SomeRandomName", "Table8907123", "Table123NoMatch"
};

var regex = new Regex(@"^Table[1-9]\d*$");

var matches = names.Select(s => regex.Match(s)).Where(match => match.Success);
foreach (var match in matches)
    ViewData.Add($"{match.Value}FillColor", "#ff1200");
```

And if you only want to match "Table1" to "Table8", you can use this `Regex` instead:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^Table[1-8]$");
```